# Android studio parcelable write an Integer

Tags: android, parcelable

Can I write an `Integer` instead of an `int` when useing parceable?

I want something like this

```
out.writeInt(myInt);
out.writeInteger(myInteger);
```

and then

```
this.myInt = in.readInt();
this.myInteger = in.readInteger();
```

But I couldn't find anything on this. Is this possible in some way? If so, how?

Comment: What would be the use case for this? Could you just parcel up the `Integer` as a primitive and re-declare as an `Integer` when reading the parcel back?

Comment: It is assigned from a data request and it is nullable

Comment: Can't you just put like... `out.writeInt( myInteger.intValue() );` and `this.myInteger = in.readInt();`

Comment: @SimonAndersson In which case I'd recommend `writeValue()` instead to preserve your `Integer` as an object`, [as per this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10769887/469080)

Comment: @MichaelDodd Thank you, it solved my problem. I marked as duplicate since the end result is the same.