# Read and Write Long Object in Android Parcelable Class

Tags: android, object, long-integer, parcelable

If say I have following with a long object. Does below example demonstrate correct way of reading and writing Long object?

```
Class MyClass implements Parcelable {
   private Long aLongObject;

    public static final Creator<MyClass> CREATOR = new Creator<MyClass>() {
    @Override
    public MyClass createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new MyClass(in);
    }

    @Override
    public MyClass[] newArray(int size) {
       .....
    }
};


protected MyClass(Parcel in) {// reading Parcel
    super(in);

  aLongObject = in.readLong(); // correct way to ready Long object?
 }

   @Override
public void writeToParcel(@NonNull Parcel dest, int flags) {
    super.writeToParcel(dest, flags);

      dest.writeLong(aLongObject); // is this correct way to send Long?
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your approach is that a `Long` value may be `null` but the `Parcel` methods only take/ return values of the primitive data type `long`, see the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcel.html#writeLong(long)) for details. So you need a workaround to store a `Long` value.

I like to use a `int` to indicate whether my `Long` value is `null` (you can only store `boolean` arrays no single `boolean` values) and a `long` to store the numerical value if it isn't:

Writing to the `Parcel`

```
int indicator = (aLongObject == null) ? 0 : 1;
long number = (aLongObject == null) ? 0 : aLongObject;
dest.writeInt(indicator); 
dest.writeLong(number);
```

Reading from the `Parcel`

```
// NOTE: reading must be in the same order as writing
Long aLongObject;
int indicator = in.readInt();
long number = in.readLong();
if(indicator == 0){
    aLongObject = null;
}
else{
    aLongObject = number;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Quick question, is above the best approach or to use  dest.writeValue and in.readValue since this is an Object?

Comment: @Akshay - what I do not understand is why you have a `class MyClass implements Parcelable` and a Constructor for `V3MemberReward` inside. There is a nice tutorial [here](https://guides.codepath.com/android/using-parcelable) which may be helpful

Comment: Sorry for the typo.. I have fixed that

Comment: @Akshay - I think using the two primitive data type values to map the `Long` value is better than working with an `Object` since `Object` creation is more expensive (memory and CPU time). OTOH I doubt it will matter much on modern devices

Answer (score 3):

You can simply use

### Write

```
dest.writeValue(this.aLongObject);
```

### Read

```
this.aLongObject = (Long)in.readValue(Long.class.getClassLoader());
```

---

`writeValue` and `readValue` handle `null` gracefully.

Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/10769887/72437